# "Угроза и подождите 10 секунд" после включение моего приложения в спец возможностях мешает запуску события в onServiceConnected()

Tags: android, accessibility

В Android 11 при тестировании обнаружил эту особенность, раньше вместо полноэкранного активити с надписью "Угроза и подождите 10 секунд", было простое разрешение, которое никак не влияло на исполнение кода в onServiceConnected(), но это же вообще не даёт коду сервиса специальных возможностей выполнится.

Вопрос, что можно сделать?

[image: Вот само активити с угрзой моему коду )]

Answer (score 0):

Крайне не информативный вопрос получился.. ведь суть решение была именно в коде, мне пришлось переместить код из onServiceConnected() в onAccessibilityEvent(). Если что код который не выполнялся, это запрос разрешений.

Как именно это помогло? В Android 11 как и во всех Android старше 10го вроде как, onServiceConnected() вызывается только при включении приложения в специальных возможностях. Вероятно, код срабатывал, но полноэкранное активити, "УГРОЗА", было приоритетнее моих активити с запросом разрешений и те тупо сворачивались вместе с этой УГРОЗОЙ. Как смог, так объяснил

Comment: Можете послезавтра принять ответ, а с вопроса удалить пометку `[ВОПРОС ЗАКРЫТ]`.